# How to make a button unclickable but Touchable?

Tags: java, android, android-resources, ontouchlistener, android-touch-event

I have a button, when I click it it makes a scale animation, and also I can drag it with onTouch event.

I want to make it unclickable after first touch and this code does. Here OnClick

```
    btnScale.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.startAnimation(animScale);
            btnScale.setClickable(false);

        }});
```

Also this code help me to drag it. Here OnTouch

```
 btnScale.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener(){

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    oldXvalue = me.getX();
                    oldYvalue = me.getY();
                } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                    //RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

                    params.leftMargin = (int) (me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2));
                    params.topMargin = (int) (me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()));

                    //LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(v.getHeight(), (int) (me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2)), (int) (me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight())));
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
                return false;
            }});
```

However I still want to drag it after I click it. However when I make it unclickable it cannot be dragable since it is unTouchable too

EDIT:

When I use if else state on onClick as boolean variable, I still able to click the button and a ugly square appears in my circular button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#61d5ee">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#61d5ee"/>
           <corners android:radius="5dp"  />
           <stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#cdf3fb" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

What to do?

Comment: make another Ontouch event with override?

Comment: Why don't you set a flag `(boolean)` on the `OnClick`?

Comment: you could subclass button, and override performClick without calling the super

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean to say if it is enabled or not, change manually the state in your onClick and change the button's design too. In your Onclick use something like:

```
if(enabled){
   do something
}else{
    //do nothing
}
```

You don't need the else, it's just an example.
Then... he is touchable enabled and disabled.

Comment: but when I do that I can still click the button and a strange square appears at the middle of my button shape.

Comment: you're using default android button?

Comment: <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#61d5ee">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#61d5ee"/>
     <corners android:radius="5dp"  />
     <stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#cdf3fb" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>

Comment: No ripple effect circular button I use